# function that checks if a radio button is check/not-checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all I'm stumped on rewriting a function from jQuery to Javascript. The function I currently have written works great but the only issue is, is that it has to be written in plain Javascript. Here is the function I have written:

```
function checkFunc() {
    if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length === 0) alert("Not checked");
    else alert("Checked");
}
```

I need the function to work the same way it does now but I just need it in Javascript! Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do with [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7_uLD96PWAhVIvY8KHY6XD18QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw)

```js
function checkFunc() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length === 0) alert("Not checked");
  else alert("Checked");
}

checkFunc()
```

```html
<input type="radio" checked>
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I spent a lot of time for that same function written in Javascript and could not find one. I appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome.@MujoM .My answer helped mark it as an answer.it's helpful for future visitors ... And Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radioBtn = document.getElementById('radioBtn');

function check() {
  if(radioBtn.checked) {
    alert('checked')
  } else {
    alert('Not Checked')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radioBtn" />

<button onclick="check()">Check For Checked</button>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :-

```
function checkFunc() {
    if (!$("input[type='radio']:checked").val()) {
        alert("Not checked")
    } else {
        alert("Checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, but I need the function in pure Javascript code, no jQuery. Thanks anyways!